# How to set Cantonese as the voice search language in a app?

Tags: java, android, iso

My current code below works fine when using the "ZH" ISO code for Mandarin but won't for Cantonese. This is the code below

```
  Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
  String myLanguage= "yue";
   i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, myLanguage);
   i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, myLanguage); 
   i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, myLanguage);
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the code working, the dash just needed replaced with a underscore to make:

**zh_HK**

Thanks for your help Lilz.

Answer (score 0):

For Cantonese
try `zh-HK` instead

Hope this helps

Comment: Nope doesn't work, have also tried: yue
YUE
zh-HK
ZH
zh-yue
HK

Comment: Did you use: EXTRA_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES to get the list of languages supported?

Comment: @Lilz hey, how do we use this constant in the application?