# Android speech recognition - Language code

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am working on some speech recognition in English, Cantonese and Chinese.

### Code for recognizing English (works well):

```
button_alert_recognize.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) 
            {          
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
                {
                    if (pressed == false)
                    {
                        String myLanguage= "en_US";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);        
                        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");
                        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, myLanguage);
                        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, myLanguage); 
                        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, myLanguage);
                        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,1); 
                        sr.startListening(intent);
                        pressed = true;
                        tv_google.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.listening));                            
                    }                       
                }
```

### Current trial and output:

For Cantonese, When I replace the `myLanguage` to `zh-yue`, `zh-HK`, `zh_HK` but all fails.

For Chinese, I have tried replacing the `myLanguage` to `cmn-Hans-CN`, `zh-CN`, zh_CN` but also all fails.

The failure message would be ERROR 4: ERROR_SERVER which almost immediately appears when the button is pressed.

### Question:

Would there be any official documentation for these basic language code? What will be the correct language code for Cantonese and Chinese?

Comment: You may check supported languages using [RecognizerIntent.getVoiceDetailsIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#getVoiceDetailsIntent%28android.content.Context%29).

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756700/how-to-set-cantonese-as-the-voice-search-language-in-a-app