# react-native-voice recognizes most languages EXCEPT Cantonese and Mandarin?

Tags: react-native

I installed `react-native-voice` to my react project and it works almost perfectly.  When I execute this line of code: `Voice.start('en-US')` on an android Huawai Nova Plus device and I say `There is a warp core breach`, my `console.log` shows an array with that exact phrase.

So I then tried some other languages and they all worked great like:

- `Voice.start('fr-CA')` and said `je suis désolé` and it printed properly
- `Voice.start('jp-JP')` and said `dai senpuu` and it printed `大旋風`
- `Voice.start('it-IT')` and said `comay sty` and it printed `come stai`

So those all seem fine and it's working.  But both Cantonese and Mandarin seems to fail.  I tried the language codes `zh-CN,zh-HK,zh-CHS,zh-CHT` but no matter what I say, the `console.log` outputs alphabet characters instead of Chinese characters.

How come Chinese doesn't work?

Comment: I checked the source on the Android side to see what library was being used. It led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756700/how-to-set-cantonese-as-the-voice-search-language-in-a-app) which suggests trying out `zh_HK`. See if that works. You may need to just read the source to find out what libraries are being used underneath to figure out the correct codes to use.

Comment: OH!! that did the job!  Why is it underscore all of a sudden?

Comment: And which file did you look at that helped you realize the `zh_HK`?  I did a grep for `en-US` and `jp-JP` but didn't see any mention of these ones..

Comment: [VoiceModule.java](https://github.com/wenkesj/react-native-voice/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/wenkesj/voice/VoiceModule.java) on the Android side. You'll see that it uses the built-in Android speech recognition modules, so you won't see any language code definitions there. You'll have to look up the Android docs to find out what they've specified (that's what I did). I haven't checked out the iOS side, but you can probably look at [Voice.m](https://github.com/wenkesj/react-native-voice/blob/master/ios/Voice/Voice.m) and see what libraries are being imported and follow that back.

Comment: As for the underscore, I have no idea. It's why I didn't post an answer cause I have yet to pinpoint the docs that point out why it's different. If you can figure it out, I too would love to know why.